# phpstorm and magento assignment please

Tags: php, magento, phpstorm

hi i need help with an assignment and honestly i have no idea what to do after step one, i'm a frontend web developer and i've only done C# i've tried the tutorials on php and phpstorm etc but no luck can anyone perhaps help me out really need this... Here it is.

...
The first three exercises might seem easy but is an important part of the test. If you have not used the tools needed before you might have to make a bit of research to solve the three first tasks.

1. Download Magento Community Edition and create at test installation
   on your own machine (and install the other things you need to run
   Magento). You can download Magento .

   2. Set up a debug tool of your choice so you can step through the Magento code line by line and see the content of the variables.
      We strongly recommend that you use PHPStorm and configure it to use
      xdebug (but Komodo or Zend Studio is also available). You can
      download trial versions so you don't have to pay until after 30
      days.
   3. Create five different simple products in backend and make sure the products are visible in front-end.  Read chapter 5 in the
      attached user manual (let me know if there was a problem with the
      attachment). Create a new attribute that is a textfield and name the
      attribute "sort_order". The attribute should be visible on your
      products in frontend. Then enter numeric values in the field
      "sort_order" for three of your products and make sure the field is
      visible in frontend.
   4. Create a new module according to the blog post: http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/create-new-module-helloworld-in-magento/
      but change the name of the module from HelloWorld to your own first
      name, change in all relevant places. Tips 1: In the blog post a
      couple of starting "

      Use the debugger in PHPStorm (or other IDE) to step through the function "match"
      (app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php) in
      the file Magento step by step carefully.  Do this many times until
      you get a feeling for what is going on. Try clicking on many
      different modules in front end and also login to backend and step
      through the same function. Write down with your own words what is
      going on inside the match function so that the reader can understand
      that you understand what is going on in this function.

      Change the module you created in step 4 so it now outputs a nice list of the products that have a value in the field
      "sort_order". The list should be sorted according to the value in
      the field "sort_order", lowest number shows first. The list should
      contain the product name and a picture of the product. When you
      click on the product name or picture you should get to the product
      detail view.

      Add a button somewhere on the page that reverse the sort order when you click it.

      Create a compressed file containing your final module and a database export and send it back. Also include your description from
      step 5. Include admin user login details for the Magento backend.

Comment: and i'm on day two. and still nowhere..

Comment: please check the site https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_installation.htm

Answer (score 0):

The following are some link that may help you out.

```html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_installation_guide
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_installation.htm
```

Thanks

Sagar